# Nautilus showing random directories

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

Not sure exactly what happened, but the sidebar of Nautilus is showing a bunch of random directories that I can't remove.

I've tried reinstalling with `sudo apt-get purge nautilus && apt-get install nautilus` among a few other things, but the corrupt directories remain. Any ideas?

[image: Picture of the sidebar]

Comment: Please add output of `gvfs-mount -l` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1199355/edit).

Comment: @N0rbert the output only showed the drives it should. I solved the problem a different way. Thanks though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, apparently the bookmark file used by Nautilus, `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`, was overwritten with an error log which resulted in the gibberish directories in the sidebar. Removing the bookmarks file then restarting to recreate it solved the problem.